# Find the best constant $C_{n}$ such this complex inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

nd we can consider this problem In general? if $|z_{1}|=|z_{2}|=\cdots=|z_{n}|=1$ if there exist complex $z(|z|=1)$ such $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{||z-z_{i}||^2}\le C_{n}$$ find the best $C_{n}$?

$$C_{n}\ge\dfrac{n}{2}?$$

Comment: It looks reasonable that $C_n$ is given by $z_k=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i k}{n}\right)$ and $z=\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{n}\right)$. Anyway, $C_n$ has to be at least quadratic with respect to $n$, since $\frac{1}{4\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2n}}\approx \frac{n^2}{\pi^2}$ for large values of $n$.

Comment: Nice .Thanks,I'm looking forward to the complete solution

Comment: I do not have it, my claim is just that the optimal inequality is attained in the mentioned case. That gives $$ C_n \stackrel{?}{=}\color{red}{\frac{n^2}{4}}$$ and proves $C_n\geq \frac{n^2}{4}$.

Comment: The general problem is hard to tackle due to too many geometrical constraints, but to take $z$ on the midpoint of the longest arc still looks as a good choice.